# How do I get data from a table?

Tags: javascript

How do I pull data (string) from a column called "Limit" in a table ("displayTable") in Javascript?

```
var table = document.getElementById('displayTable');    
var rowCount = table.rows.length;    
for (var i = 1; i < rowCount - 1; i++) {    
     var row = table.rows[i]["Limit"].ToString();
     alert(row);
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is how I accomplished reading a table in javascript.  Basically I drilled down into the rows and then I was able to drill down into the individual cells for each row.
This should give you an idea

```
//gets table
var oTable = document.getElementById('myTable');

//gets rows of table
var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;

//loops through rows    
for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){

   //gets cells of current row
   var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;

   //gets amount of cells of current row
   var cellLength = oCells.length;

   //loops through each cell in current row
   for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){
      /* get your cell info here */
      /* var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML; */
   }
}
```

**UPDATED SCRIPT**

```js
//gets table
var oTable = document.getElementById('myTable');

//gets rows of table
var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;

//loops through rows    
for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){

  //gets cells of current row  
   var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;

   //gets amount of cells of current row
   var cellLength = oCells.length;

   //loops through each cell in current row
   for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){
      // get your cell info here

      var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML;
      console.log(cellVal);
   }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td>B3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have made progress with the snippet. innerHTML seem to be empty which is strange because that is how I added the data when entering the data in my javascript code.    

var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);  cell4.innerHTML = limit;

Comment: cell4.innerHTML = limit;
What is limit?

I think if you assign a variable to cell4.innerHTML you will get what is in that cell (assuming you set everything up correctly and there is actual data).

Comment: OK I just created a test page and tested the script.  I edited my original answer to alert our each cell in the table.  From here I think you should be able to get what you are needing.

Comment: I see where I was going wrong.  The for loop didnt need a rowLength - 2... in my case at least.  I really appreciate this

Comment: @user54197: the -2 on the rowLength in my original snippet was remnant of the code I had used prior... 

I'm glad it worked for you!

Comment: This doesn't deal with cells with a rowspan attribute.

Answer (score 15):

In this code `data` is a two dimensional array of table data

```js
let oTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
let data = [...oTable.rows].map(t => [...t.children].map(u => u.innerText))
console.log(data);
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td>B3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7):

use Json & jQuery. It's way easier than oldschool javascript

```
function savedata1() { 

var obj = $('#myTable tbody tr').map(function() {
var $row = $(this);
var t1 = $row.find(':nth-child(1)').text();
var t2 = $row.find(':nth-child(2)').text();
var t3 = $row.find(':nth-child(3)').text();
return {
    td_1: $row.find(':nth-child(1)').text(),
    td_2: $row.find(':nth-child(2)').text(),
    td_3: $row.find(':nth-child(3)').text()
   };
}).get();
```