# Save HTML data into database by client side processing

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery, client-side

I need to save a dynamic table data generated at the client side into the database.

My dynamic table is as follows :

```
<table class="table" id = "myTable">
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Roll No</th>
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>Attendance</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <?php foreach($results as $students) {?>
          <tr id="<?= $students->roll_no;?>" align ="center">
            <td><?= $students->roll_no;?></td>
            <td><?= $students->full_name;?></td>
            <td><input type="radio" id="att" name="attendance" value="present">Present
<input type="radio" id="att" name="attendance" value="absent">Absent</td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>                                                        
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" onClick="savedata()" name="submit" value="SAVE">
```

The twist here is that I am using a radio button in my third column and hence need to pass the checked value on SUBMIT

The javascript code (Reference : [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248869/how-do-i-get-data-from-a-data-table-in-javascript))I am using is :

> function savedata()
>         {
>             var oTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
>             //gets table
>
> ```
>       var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
>       //gets rows of table
>
>       for (i = 1; i < rowLength; i++){
>       //loops through rows
>
>          var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;
>          //gets cells of current row
>          var cellLength = oCells.length;
>              for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){
>              //loops through each cell in current row
>                 <!--get your cell info here-->
>                 if(j == cellLength-1)
>                 {
>                       var cellVal = $('input[name="attendance"]:radio:checked');
>                       alert(cellVal);
>                                         // store it in array here
>                                        radioarr = [oTable.rows.item(i).cells,oCells.item(j).innerHTML]; 
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                       var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML;
>                       alert(cellVal);
>                                         // store it in array here 
>                                        fieldarr = [oTable.rows.item(i).cells,oCells.item(j).innerHTML];
>                 }
>              }
>
>       }
>   }
>   $.ajax{
>
>       // Pass the data to another page insert.php and store it in the database
>   }
> </script>
> ```

So what I need to do is.. Make a key value pair and store it in an array and pass it as an ajax request and insert the same in the database.

Issues :

1. The checked radio button is not getting stored in the array
2. I need to create a 2D array and store all the data there and wen I created its showing [object,object]
3. I need to pass this array using an ajax request into another page and store it in the database.

Please help me how can I do this ?

Thanks in advance. NC

Comment: If you know the steps you need to take, can you show us the code that you've written to take those steps? Where in those steps are you getting stuck?

Comment: You're going to need to use jQuery's [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [`post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method. Short of giving a complete tutorial on AJAX, it will be difficult to provide more pointers without seeing example code of where your attempts at using AJAX are failing.

Comment: @John: I have explained the issues in my edit

Comment: i would suggest creating json object of the data you get from the table and do ajax query to a php file where u do json_decode ..

Comment: @MattB : Firstly I need to store the data into an array and then pass it. Problem is I am not able to store the data in array itself :(

Comment: @Dinesh : I am a newbie in javscript and JSON. I dont know how it works.. can please provide me a demonstration if u dont mind

Comment: I'm guessing your goal could be accomplished in an easier way than looping through the cells of the HTML table. If you just want to grab all the data from the form and send it via AJAX, you can use this plugin: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/. Or for a more customized solution, check out http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/.

Comment: @MattB : I am not understanding the serializeArray() and not able to relate it with my code.. Any good example for better understanding

Comment: In your table you create a radio button group by giving all radio buttons in the table the same name attribute value. So all radio buttons in the table are in same group. If it wasn't by intention you should use different name for each row, like attendance_01, attendance_02 and so on.

Comment: @NealCaffrey There are many other places online full of people that will do all the coding work for you, sadly enough some people at SO still don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.. I have modified your code to fix some errors..

```
<table class="table" id = "myTable">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Roll No</th>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Attendance</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <?php foreach($results as $students) {?>
      <tr id="<?= $students["roll_no"];?>" align ="center">
        <td id="roll_no"><?= $students["roll_no"];?></td>
        <td id="full_name"><?= $students["full_name"];?></td>

         <!-- Attendance has to be unique for each row -->
        <td id="attendance"><input type="radio" id="att" name="attendance_<?= $students["roll_no"] ?>" value="present">Present
            <input type="radio" id="att" name="attendance_<?= $students["roll_no"]?>" value="absent">Absent</td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>                                                        
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
  <script>

    function savedata() { 
        var roll_no = "";
        var jsonObject = '[';
        var oTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
    //gets table

    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
    //gets rows of table

    for (i = 1; i < rowLength; i++){
    //loops through rows
        jsonObject += "{";
       var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;
       //gets cells of current row
       var cellLength = oCells.length;
           for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){

           //loops through each cell in current row
              <!--get your cell info here-->
              //added cell name so that I can create json id
              var cellName = oCells.item(j).id;
              var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML;

              if(j==0)
                  roll_no = cellVal;
              if(cellVal.search('radio')>0){
                  var cellVal = $('input[name="attendance_'+roll_no+'"]:radio:checked').val();
              }
              // A dirty way to creat json
              jsonObject += '"' +cellName + '":"' + cellVal + '",';

           }
           jsonObject = jsonObject.slice(0,jsonObject.length-1);
           jsonObject += '},';
        }
        jsonObject = jsonObject.slice(0,jsonObject.length-1);
        jsonObject += ']';

       // the json looks like this for 3 rows depending on what radio button u select
       // [{"roll_no":"10","full_name":"Name 1","attendance":"present"},{"roll_no":"14","full_name":"Name 2","attendance":"absent"},{"roll_no":"18","full_name":"Name 3","attendance":"present"}]

        //send this data to a php page
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data:"json=" + jsonObject,
            processData: false, 
            dataType: 'json'
        });

      }
</script>
```

ajax.php is the file where you will post the json data.

```
<?php

    $value = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["json"])); 
    print_r($value);
?>
```

Inside your ajax.php you can write code to save this data to database ot text file whatever you want to do with it. If you print you get the following output.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [roll_no] => 10
        [full_name] => Name 1
        [attendance] => present
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [roll_no] => 14
        [full_name] => Name 2
        [attendance] => absent
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [roll_no] => 18
        [full_name] => Name 3
        [attendance] => present
    )
)
```

This is the most ugly way to do it.. It can be done with much less number of line and more efficiently by using only JQuery. I just wanted to show you how it can be done with the code you provided. Let me know if you have any questions.

Dins

> EDITED...

Better way to do this

```
function savedata1() { 

var obj = $('#myTable tbody tr').map(function() {
    var $row = $(this);
    var roll = $row.find(':nth-child(1)').text();
    var atd = $row.find('td input[name="attendance_'+roll+'"]:radio:checked').val()
    return {
        roll_no: $row.find(':nth-child(1)').text(),
        full_name: $row.find(':nth-child(2)').text(),
        attendance: atd
    };
}).get();

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data:"json=" + JSON.stringify(obj),
        processData: false, 
        dataType: 'json'
    });

}
```

Comment: Oh Thanks a lot for the code.. Can u tell me a better approach.. I just couldnt find a better way so had to do like this.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to decode json in PHP file just use

```
 $value = stripslashes($_POST["json"]);
```