# JQuery UI Modal Form Dialog Save Data To Database

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am using the [JQuery UI Modal Form Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)  and trying to save the old data and new data to a database. I am using C# (backend) and ASP.NET front end. I can delete new entries, I just don't know how to save the data. I have tried searching ways to pull pull the HTML data in, but couldn't get rid of the errors. Also Wasn't sure if there was a better method? Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdiddy1792/ed8Nq/2/)

```
function addUser() {
```

I need to figure out a way to get the data from the table and post it to the server.

Comment: not really clear where problems are. Getting form to submit? Or server related code

Comment: I didn't see the form being submitted

Comment: My code works but what it is missing is for the backend (c#) to be able to get all the information in the table some how. - how can I reference the table to possibly parse through it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:

[This script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248869/how-do-i-get-data-from-a-data-table-in-javascript) gets data from the table that you can then parse through.

You could then pass it into a hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you may be looking for is web methods, it allows the jquery (client side) to call the backend (c#) and for them to interact with each other.

Check out this link for reference:
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Here is a brief summary from the website:

> When it comes to lightweight client-side communication, I’ve noticed
>   that many of you prefer ASP.NET AJAX’s page methods to full ASMX web
>   services. In fact, page methods came up in the very first comment on
>   my article about using jQuery to consume ASMX web services. Given
>   their popularity, I’d like to give them their due attention. As a
>   result of Justin‘s question in those comments, I discovered that you
>   can call page methods via jQuery. In fact, it turns out that you can
>   even do it without involving the ScriptManager at all. In this post, I
>   will clarify exactly what is and isn’t necessary in order to use page
>   methods. Then, I’ll show you how to use jQuery to call a page method
>   without using the ScriptManager.