# Extracting data from a table in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it considered bad practice to send data to a back-end application, from an html page that does not contain a `<form>` or any `<input>` elements?

Basically, I have a situation where I have to take some data from an html page, pass it to a back-end application, process it and then return some resulting data. Normally, I would have some kind of an html form to extract the data from... However, in my case, I am stuck with nothing but a table. Also, the `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` elements do not have any `id`. What would be the best way to go about extracting data from the html form to send back using javascript?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248869/how-do-i-get-data-from-a-data-table-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Here I take the table row value on click event. You may pass them to server using ajax post.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <table>
    <thead>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Age</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>80</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("table tbody tr").on("click",function(e){
                var rowValue = $(this).context.innerText.split("\t");
                alert(rowValue);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of objects with each object having an index to a column with its value set the columns inner text.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>R1:C1</td>
    <td>R1:C2</td>
    <td>R1:C2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>R2:C1</td>
    <td>R2:C2</td>
    <td>R2:C2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>R3:C1</td>
    <td>R3:C2</td>
    <td>R3:C2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>R3:C1</td>
    <td>R3:C2</td>
    <td>R3:C2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
var data=[];
$('table tr').each(function(i ,e) 
{
  var row={};
  $(e).find("td").each(function(n,k) {
    row[n]=$(k).text();
  })
  data.push(row);
});
console.log(data);
//Result
/*
[
  {
"0": "R1:C1",
"1": "R1:C2",
"2": "R1:C2"
  },
  {
"0": "R2:C1",
"1": "R2:C2",
"2": "R2:C2"
  },
  {
"0": "R3:C1",
"1": "R3:C2",
"2": "R3:C2"
  },
  {
"0": "R3:C1",
"1": "R3:C2",
"2": "R3:C2"
  }
]
*/
</script>
```