# How to get data from a html row (in a table) with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Im trying to get the information inside my dynamic table when someone clicks on it, so I can read column by column and extract the data, to then show it in a textbox. Dont know how to do it since im new to this languages, hope you can help. What im doing at the moment is exctrating the data from my database and creating the dynamic table with it.
I´ve already tried a couple things, but none of them worked so I´m not going to paste all the failed attempts here. 
This is my code (since a lot of people had problems with it being mysql I updated it to Mysqli_:

```
    if (($result)||(mysqli_errno == 0))
{
 echo "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' width='126%'>
 <tr>
  <td>
   </table>
 <div style='width:450; height:350px; overflow:auto;'>
 <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1' border='1' width='380px'>
   <tr style='color:white;background-colorgrey'>";
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
 {
      //loop thru the field names to print the correct headers
      $i = 0;
      while ($i < mysqli_num_fields($result))
      {
          $fetch = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i);
          echo "<th>". $fetch->name . "</th>";
          $i++;
  }
 //display the data
 while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach ($rows as $data)
  {
    echo "<td align='center' width='400px'>". $data . "</td>";
  }
  echo"</tr>";
}
 }else{
   echo "<tr><td colspan='" . ($i+1) . "'>No Results found!</td></tr>";
 }
   echo "</table></div>";
```

Comment: Where is the closing tag of this line `<tr style='color:white;background-colorgrey'>";`?

Comment: Do you have an Output? BTW: mysql_* is already deprecated. Use mysqli_* instead!

Comment: Forgot closing the tr! Seems to work fine tho ^^. @Virb

Comment: I cannot show the output because it has sensitive data from the company I work with. Will change to mysqli_ soon ty! Just wanted to finish this first.  @Bernhard

Comment: I don't want to see your Data.. but what is displayed. Do you get the Table displayed? Or is it just a blank Page?

Comment: Yeah it shows data, works fine. It´s just a simple table with rows/columns filled with numbers and text. @Bernhard

Comment: So this Script works fine and you want to have these Data in a Form?

Comment: Yeah, I need to take the information out of the selected row, and show it in a form (saving it in a variable for each column would work too). @Bernhard

Comment: why are you still creating code using the deprecated `mysql_` library? It was discontinued several years ago due to security issues and removed entirely in PHP7. Among other issues it doesn't let you use SQL parameters to protect your data from injection attacks. I strongly suggest you migrate asap to either the `mysqli_` or `PDO` library. Apart from any security issues, once you upgrade to PHP7 your current code will simply cease to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248869/how-do-i-get-data-from-a-data-table-in-javascript this might help you with reading from the table. You just need to do that inside an event handler when someone clicks on the relevant place in the page.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson, I´m changing to Mysqli_ soon and will also check that link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in the answer, I figured it out (the variable "id" stores the element from the column "0" but you can change the 0 to get different columns):

```
        <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' width='126%'>
  <tr>
  <td>
   </table>
 <div style='width:450; height:350px; overflow:auto;'>
 <table style="display: table-row" class='prueba' cellspacing='0'              cellpadding='1' border='1' width='380px'>
    <tbody>
    <tr style='color:white;background-colorgrey'>

   <?php

   ///******///
  ///CONECTION AND QUERY INFO WOULD GO HERE///
  ///******///

  if (($result)||(mysqli_errno == 0))
 {

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
  {
      //loop thru the field names to print the correct headers
      $i = 0;
      echo "<th><a>Check</a></th>";
      while ($i < mysqli_num_fields($result))
      {
          $fetch = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i);
   echo "<th><a>". $fetch->name . "</a></th>";
   $i++;
  }
   //display the data
   while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
   echo "<tr onClick='Content(this)'>";
   foreach ($rows as $data)
   {
    echo "<td align='center' width='400px'><a>". $data . "</a></td>";
  }
  echo"</tr>";
  }
  }/*else{
   echo "<tr><td colspan='" . ($i+1) . "'>No Results found!</td></tr>";
     }*/

  }else{
   echo "'Error in running query :'. mysqli_error()";
   }    

  //echo "<style>";

 /*echo "</tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>
      <table min-width='400px' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'       border='1'>";*/

 echo "</table></div>";
 echo "<script>
    function Content(elem){
        elem.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

        var id = $(elem).find('td:eq(0)').text();
        alert(id);}
        </script>";
  ?>
  </p>
```