# How to get table cell data using javascript

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a table like this,

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">This</td>   
    <td>Little1</td>     
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Little2</td>       
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Little3</td>     
  </tr>    
</table>
```

How to get table cell data "Little2" using javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get data from a data table in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248869/how-do-i-get-data-from-a-data-table-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is using the function `querySelector`

```
document.querySelector('table tr:nth-child(2) td')
```

```js
var text = document.querySelector('table tr:nth-child(2) td').textContent;
console.log(text)
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">This</td>   
    <td>Little1</td>     
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Little2</td>       
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Little3</td>     
  </tr>    
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an id for the table and use the `document.getElementById("tableid_goes_here").rows[i].cells[j]` arrays.