# Using a for loop on a table or array to combine multiple entries for the same categories

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Table comes from a MySQL query 
[image: Example Table]

The Web Page my code currently builds:
[image: Web Page]

The data for the table comes from a DB using JDBC result set to connect DB to Google Apps Script, then that query is then used to create a Google Sheet.
As you can see, the `for` loop in the HTML page produces multiple departments for each employee that's in that department. I would like a way to combine those, for example, all employees with *Production:Shop* in Column A should be in a single "Production:Shop" column in the webpage. Can the `for` loop be altered to produce that, or do I adjust the query?

My Apps Script `HtmlTemplate` code to build the web page (the `<?` and `<?=` scriptlet tags allow using JS variables during template evaluation):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <header> 
    <h1 class="Title">Current Status</h1>
  </header>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
  <? for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){ ?>
    <div>
    <!--<h2><?= data[i].Employee ?></h2>-->
    </div>
    <div class="data">
      <div class="dataHeader">
        <h2 class="dataHeaderText">
          <?= data[i].task_name ?>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <h2> Current Workers</h2>
      <div class="col-container">
        <div class="col" style="background:#535351">
          <h2>Employees</h2><hr> 
          <h4><?= data[i].LastFirstName ?> <br/> </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col" style="background:#0b3e6b">
          <h2>Date/Time</h2><hr>
          <h4> <?=
            (data[i].DateTime.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
            data[i].DateTime.getDate() + "/" +
            data[i].DateTime.getFullYear() + " " +
            data[i].DateTime.getHours() + ":" + data[i].DateTime.getMinutes();
          ?> </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col" style="background:#535351">
          <h2>Duration</h2><hr>
          <h4> <?= data[i].Duration + "\r" ?> </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <? } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) please.

Comment: @VincentNguyen yeah tried  GROUP_CONCAT() with line break '\n' as a separator in MySQL query looked good on the google sheets  table but didn't show up well on the web page

Comment: @RandyCasburn perhaps if you would enlighten me on what part of the question your not understanding, I could be able to able to clean it up for you.Thanks.

Comment: In essence what you want to do is loop through departments and for each department loop through name. I'm not sure what your workflow is like since you just threw a MySQL command at me but that's what the idea is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get data from a data table in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248869/how-do-i-get-data-from-a-data-table-in-javascript)

Comment: @VincentNguyen I'm using google apps script as my IDE and then obtaining data from company database using JDBC Result set, the  GROUP_CONCAT() was used in the query there, then that query can be transformed into a google spreadsheet. Ddi this help you any?

Comment: So this isn't really a javascript question I think. You want to know how to query multiple columns in a google sheet. If you have a more focused question of javascript I can help you more but I am not too familiar with MySQL and its connection with google sheets.

Comment: @VincentNguyen JS is used throughout the manufacturing of the spreadsheet and building the HTML page this, this <? ?> allows me to use JS on the HTML page that's where I am using the for loop to recreate the same container that houses the data from the table. Thanks, I appreciate you trying to help me.

Comment: Can you post your code where you are trying to loop through the table? It should not be too difficult, just need a nested for loop

Comment: @VincentNguyen Hope you meant posting it herein the comments

<? for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){ ?>

<div>
<!--<h2><?= data[i].Employee ?></h2>-->
</div>
<div class="data">
<div class="dataHeader">
<h2 class="dataHeaderText">
<?= data[i].task_name ?>
</h2>
</div>
<h2> Current Workers</h2>
<div class="col-container">
<div class="col" style="background:#535351">
<h2>Employees</h2><hr> 
<h4><?= data[i].LastFirstName ?> <br/> </h4>
</div>
</ } ?>

Comment: I meant in the original post so it's readable

Comment: How do I get data from a data table in javascript? Does not solve my problem @RandyCasburn.For example all employees names, date/time and duration under  Grocery needs to be combined into one.Thanks, for your understanding

Comment: @VincentNguyen sorry hope you can see it now in the post

Comment: Is that code up there building the table in the screenshot? Doesn't look like they match up. Can you show what `data` contains?

Comment: @VincentNguyen No, that code does not build that table it builds  the web page. data is an array that's used to house the information from DB then it used to create a table in google sheets. so, in essence, that table is data. I just changed task_name to Departments. Do you understand? would like to see what the page looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by changing your data, and also by changing your [`HtmlTemplate`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template) code - your database query doesn't need to change.

Currently, you have a `for` loop with a single level, and don't check for equivalency between the entries in your query result. Thus, you get 1 webpage column for each row. To concatenate employees from the same department into the same column - so you have only 1 webpage column per department, rather than 1 webpage column per query result - you must change the result you are using.

One possible change, is to use change the `data` variable from an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) into an associative [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), so that it is like `{"Operations:Accounting":{"John Smith":{clockTime: ..., duration: 3.56}, "Jane Doe":{clockTime: ..., duration: 0.53}, ... }, "Production:Shop": {...}, ... }`.
Then you would adjust your `for` loop to access every property (an "Employee" object) of every key (a "Department" object) of your `data` Object. Note that this is a nested for-loop.

```
function serveWebpage(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("myfile");
  template.data = transformQueryResult_(getQueryResult_(e));
  return template.evaluate();
}

function transformQueryResult_(queryArray) {
  var output = {},
      departmentIndex = 0,
      employeeNameIndex = 1,
      clockIndex = 2,
      durationIndex = 3;
  for (var r = 0; r < queryArray.length; ++r) {
    var row = queryArray[r];
    var dept = row[departmentIndex],
        empName = row[employeeNameIndex],
        clock = row[clockIndex],
        duration = row[durationIndex];

    // Create this department if necessary.
    if (!output[dept]) output[dept] = {};

    // Create this employee if necessary.
    if (!output[dept][empName]) output[dept][empName] = {};

    // Set the employee's clockTime property and duration property
    // Assumption: an employee appears only once in the query for a given department.
    // (i.e. only a single clockTime and duration for an employee will be displayed)
    output[dept][empName].clockTime = row[clockIndex];
    output[dept][empName].duration = row[durationIndex];
  }
  return output;
}
```

In your `HtmlTemplate` file, you'd then iterate over the departments, and then the employees, using the [scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets) as necessary:

```
for (var dept in data) {
  /* Add code to create a webpage column for the department roster */
  for (var emp in data[dept]) {
    /* Add code to use the data[dept][emp].clockTime and data[dept][emp].duration values */
  }
  /* Add necessary closing tags for the column*/
}
```

---

As a note, it's probably going to be better for your end users if you follow Apps Script best practices and load the query result asynchronously - i.e. without any scriptlets at all, just [client-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to help an up and coming developer. Your solution worked perfectly and I learned a new way to solve this problem in the future. Thank you so much.