# Read table cell by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created table with several columns, one column with textarea field and one with button to save textarea value.

First thing I want to read textarea field. I use this code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
        $("#myTable").on('click','.btnSelect',function(){
             // get the current row
             var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr"); 

             var colT=currentRow.find("td:eq(7)").text(); // OR
             var colTa=currentRow.find("textarea").text();

             alert(colT + colTa);
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Anyway I receive the original value from table, but I need new or updated value.

Comment: We can't help you without seeing a sample of the HTML too

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248869/how-do-i-get-data-from-a-data-table-in-javascript

Comment: did you try `.val()` on `textarea`?

Comment: .val() returns new value. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide your HTML because .find('textarea') is working,need to check with your HTML structure

Comment: I changed .text() into .val() and it works. Thank you.