# I would like to read a table. How can I access the next tr:

Tags: jquery, html

The user fills in a table that I want to read out afterwards 
How can I read the first tr and then the next tr?

```
<table id = "address">
    <body>
        <tr>
            <td class = "name"> Otto </ td>
            <td class = "plz"> 8000 </ td>
            <td class = "city"> Munich </ td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "name"> Otto </ td>
            <td class = "plz"> 8000 </ td>
            <td class = "City"> Munich </ td>
        </tr>
         ...
         ...
    </body>
</table>
<button type = "button" id = "take_Adr"> Go </ button>
<Script>
    $ ("# take_Adr"). click (function () {
        Number_tr = document.getElementById ('address').  GetElementsByTagName ('tr'). Length - 1;
    for (var i = 1; i <number_tr; i ++) {
        ???? next tr ???
        $ (this'). attr ('id', 'work');
        read_Adresse ();
        $ ( '# Work') removeAttr ( 'id').
   }
})
</ Script>
```

Thanks for a tip!

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248869/how-do-i-get-data-from-a-data-table-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248951/7004388) - I've corrected your code. You should be able to fetch the table's data by looping through each column of every row and getting the value of it using `innerText` property.

```js
function go() {
  var oTable = document.getElementById('address');
  var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
  //loops through rows    
  for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
    //gets cells of current row  
    var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;
    //gets amount of cells of current row
    var cellLength = oCells.length;
    //loops through each cell in current row
    for (var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++) {
      var cellValue = oCells.item(j).innerText;
      console.log(cellValue);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table id="address">
    <tr>
      <td class="name"> Otto </td>
      <td class="plz"> 8000 </td>
      <td class="city"> Munich </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name"> Otto </td>
      <td class="plz"> 8000 </td>
      <td class="City"> Munich </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="button" id="take_Adr" onclick="go()"> Go </button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has `$.each()` that can be used for looping - see the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

With that in mind, it makes it very easy to loop over elements. Here is one possible approach:

```
$("#take_Adr").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevents default button action        
    let tablerows = $("#take_Adr tr"); // stores all tr elements
    let names = {}; // initiate names object
    let plzs = {}; // initiate plzs object
    let cities = {}; // initiate cities object
    $.each(tablerows, function(index) { // loops through each tr element
         tr = $(this); // $(this) refers to current tr
         names[index] = tr.find(".name").text();
         plzs[index] = tr.find(".plz").text();
         cities[index] = tr.find(".city").text();
    )};
)};
```